# Apache default directory

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4, apache2.2

Let's say we have apache installed in /etc/apache2 and that we have the following configuration :

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/TestWebsite"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have a simple question about the directory `'/'`, is it pointing to the apache directory (`/etc/apache2` in my case) or to the DocumentRoot path (`/var/www/html/TestWebsite`) , or to the `linux system root directory` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Linux root. You need that for symlinks in docroot to locations outside Docroot to avoid system scans etc.

In case of  it would be DocRoot.